# Execute docker command in Docker container Azure DevOps Pipeline agent

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have created a Self Hosted Docker container agent in Azure DevOps.

Now, in Azure DevOps. I have created a pipeline and I am using the Self Hosted COntainer Agent to execute the docker run command. On trying that I am getting an error stating docker daemon is not running.

Post that I tried to execute sudo `systemctl enable docker`; `sudo systemctl start docker`; etc. but unfortunately, this did not work as I was asked for a password.

Please let me know if more clarity is needed.

Comment: As it's self-hosted docker container agent, if you start the docker on local machine and jump in the docker, are you able to run the `docker run` command inside?

Comment: No, I am getting an error message saying "Is your docker daemon running?"

Comment: Hi @SANDEEPKUMAR, the container on agent should use host's daemon, you can have the setting as my reply, let me know if it works and if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Running Docker commands inside a container to manage other containers is known as Docker Inside Docker (DinD), both containers should use host's daemon which is mentioned in official [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops#mounting-volumes-using-docker-within-a-docker-container).

To achieve this, you can mount the Docker socket (usually located at /var/run/docker.sock) into your container. This allows the container to communicate with the Docker daemon on the host.

To start the agent:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-e AZP_URL=<YOUR-ORGANIZATION-URL> \
-e AZP_TOKEN=<YOUR-TOKEN> \
-e AZP_AGENT_NAME='Ubuntu Docker' devopsubuntu-docker:latest
```

You can check the links below for more details:

[Self-hosted Azure DevOps agents running in Docker](https://robertoprevato.github.io/Self-hosted-Azure-DevOps-agents-running-in-Docker/)

[Running Docker commands inside Docker containers (on Windows)](https://intothecloud.blog/2021/08/01/Running-Docker-inside-Docker-containers/)